# httplib POST to REST server is not working correctly (characters of body are missing)

Tags: python, json, rest, httplib

I've stumbled upon a weird situation where by using httplib as my http client to a REST server (not implemented by me but fully functional) is chopping off characters at the end of the http request body. Specifically im trying to send a JSON message which I know for sure since im printing it that its correct (i've validated it) but when being received from the server its missing 2 chars at the end so the server JSON parsing is failing.

This is really weird as the message is correct when sent via curl and via java httpconnection but with python httplib im having this problem only with POST having a JSON body (no problem for POST with no body or GET).

my function code is very simple and looks like the following:

```
def sendReq(endpoint, port, method, url, msg, headers)
    client = httplib.HTTPConnection(endpoint, port)
    client.set_debuglevel(1)

    client.request(method, url, msg, headers)

    resp = client.getresponse()
    print resp.status, resp.reason

    client.close()
```

note: I'm using python 2.7.x and the message im sending is approx 250-750 characters

Comment: I can't repro this.  Can you please edit your question to show the JSON you're sending in `msg` and any `headers`?

Comment: @ChrisNauroth solved my problem by just moving httplib2 which has almost identical functionality... I dont understand the problem as I changed nothing regarding the json im sending... I prefer not to expose the json i was sending... anyway thanks for trying it!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found a solution.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is better to use the **python-requests** module, httplib module is near to be deprecated...

Regards